# Java regex replace the group value in original string

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a specific requirement to find a pattern and replace the value of matching group(2) in the original string by retaining the pattern(delimiter), I am using the pattern

```
:(\w+)[:\|]+(.*)
```

With this pattern it parse the values correctly but i am not able to replace the value of group(2). For example i have a multi-line input string

```
:20:9405601140
:2D::11298666
:28C:20/1
```

I want to replace the value(9405601140) of tag 20 with new value(1234) so the output i am expecting is

```
:20:1234
:2D::11298666
:28C:20/1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
input = input.replaceAll("(:20):(\\d+)(?!\\d)", "$1:1234");
```

Here `(\\d+)(?!\\d)` is checking whether the digits `after the :20:` are not followed by a digit or not.

However, if you want to replace only the `:20:9405601140` there here it is much simple:

```
input = input.replaceAll(":20:9405601140(?!\\d)", ":20:1234");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it the other way around.

Create a pattern like this `(:(\w+)[:\|]+)(.*)` then for each row output the first group and your replacement (instead of group 2).

Here is an working example http://ideone.com/9TkGx6

Comment: This solutions works only if the tag value is in the same line, if tag value is mulit line like :20:123213\n45555\n67788 then it only replaces 123213 but the next two lines still stays...i tired using MULTILINE and DOTALL but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by capturing what you want to keep, instead of what you want to replace, and then using a backreference (`$1`, for the first capturing group) in the replacement string to include it in the final result.

Something like:

```
string.replaceAll("(:\\w+[:\\|]+).*", "$11234")
```

To perform the replacement on all the given lines, or just:

```
string.replaceAll("(:20[:\\|]+).*", "$11234")
```

To perform the replacement only on the line beginning with ":20".

Comment: Tag 20 may be repeating and the value(9405601140) can be part of other tags as well, i want to replace specific tag and specific occurrence value only, i have option to give occurrence to replace, so need to go  by using find and as soon as i find the occurrence i have to replace it.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you.  If you only need to replace the first instance, then use `String.replaceFirst`.  If that's not what you are asking for, I'd need some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\A(?::[:\\|])\\w+", "1234");
```